# Подсчет одинаковых символов в строке

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Вроде все работает, но по условию препода символы и верхнего регистра должны быть приняты как одинаковы, то есть "А"=="а". Как можно это реализовать?

Предоставляю код: `

int main()

{

```
char str[255];
int chars[256] = { 0 };

cin >> str;

for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    chars[str[i]]++;

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    if (chars[i])
        cout << char(i) << " zamechen " << chars[i] << " raz" << endl;
```

}`

Comment: Переводите при подсчете символы в верхний регистр.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int j = 0; j <= 255; j++) 
        if (str[j]>0) str[j] = toupper(str[j]);
```

Перед этим необходимо подключить заголовочный файл "algorithm"

Comment: Вместо хитрого `if`а я бы сделал просто `str[j] = toupper((unsigned char)str[j]);`. И инклуд - не `<algorithm>`, а `<cctype>`.